# Cocos2d-x adding tag to extended CCNode disappear when insert in to CCDictionary

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I try to set tag and it does successfully but when i insert the CCnode in to CCDictionary
and try to get the CCNode and checking the tag , its 0.

```
int tagNum = 242;   
    //Gem is class Gem :public CCNode , public CCTargetedTouchDelegate 
    Gem *thisGem = new Gem();
    thisGem->retain();
    thisGem->setTag(tagNum);
    thisGem->initWithGame(this,zorder);
    int t1 = thisGem->getTag();
    // t1 = 242
    //set in container
    std::string gemID = thisGem->getGemId();
    gemsDictionary->setObject(thisGem,gemID); //gemsDictionary init in the contracture 
    Gem *nextGemTest = (Gem *)gemsDictionary->objectForKey(gemID); 
    int t2 = nextGemTest->getTag();
    // t2 is 0 ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `std::map<std::string, Gem *>` instead of `CCDictionary`

Comment: why ? what is wrong in CCDictionary, i want to understand why it happen

Comment: You should look into CCDictionary source, maybe it uses tag for own porpuses.

Comment: did you check if thisGem->getGemId() is changing the tag value? If you are developing using xcode, you could "watch" the tag value for changes and find the culprit.